# Calculating distance from polygon to point

Tags: python, polygon, distance, geopandas

```py
t1 = Polygon([(4.338074,50.848677), (4.344961,50.833264), (4.366227,50.840809), (4.367945,50.852455), (4.346693,50.858306)])
t = geopandas.GeoSeries(t1)
t.crs = {'init':'espg:4326'}

t2 = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(4.382617,50.811948)])
t2.crs = {'init':'espg:4326'}
```

How can I calculate the distance of a point from the polygon respectively find the closest point between the polygon and the point?

Answer (score 9):

Geopandas GeoSeries has a method [distance](http://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=distance#geopandas.GeoSeries.distance) which [uses Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.distance) to calculate distances:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import geopandas

t1 = Polygon([(4.338074,50.848677), (4.344961,50.833264), (4.366227,50.840809), (4.367945,50.852455), (4.346693,50.858306)])
t = geopandas.GeoSeries(t1)
t.crs = 4326

t2 = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(4.382617,50.811948)])
t2.crs = 4326

dist = t.distance(t2)
print(dist)
```

Please notice that shapely assumes coordinates on a cartesian plane. Therefore the Geopandas/Shapely distance function is not useful when using geographic coordinates. You should transform your data to a projected coordinate system before calculating distances using Geopandas/Shapely.

Comment: Okay, here I'm confused. How can project the coordinates? I'm already using espg:4326

Comment: @DaniPeer have you figured it out?

Comment: t = t.to_crs(f"EPSG:{epsg}")

Comment: what is the unit of output distance here?

Answer (score 6):

The assumption in the answer is that points are outside the polygon. If a point is inside the polygon, then it returns 0.

The nearest distance between the point and the polygon, regardless of point's position, is: `t.boundary.distance(t2)`